# OpenMP parallel for reduction delivers wrong results

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, reduction

I am working with a signal matrix and my goal is to calculate the sum of all elements of a row. The matrix is represented by the following struct:

```
typedef struct matrix {
  float *data;
  int rows;
  int cols;
  int leading_dim;
} matrix;
```

I have to mention the matrix is stored in column-major order (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order), which should explain the formula `column * tan_hd.rows + row` for retrieving the correct indices.

```
for(int row = 0; row < tan_hd.rows; row++) {
    float sum = 0.0;
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for(int column = 0; column < tan_hd.cols; column++) {
        sum += tan_hd.data[column * tan_hd.rows + row];
    }
    printf("row %d: %f", row, sum);
}
```

Without the OpenMP pragma, the delivered result is correct and looks like this:

```
row 0: 8172539.500000 row 1: 8194582.000000
```

As soon as I add the `#pragma omp...` as described above, a different (wrong) result is returned:

```
row 0: 8085544.000000 row 1: 8107186.000000
```

In my understanding, `reduction(+:sum)` creates private copies of `sum` for each thread, and after completing the loop these partial results are summed up and written back to the global variable `sum` again. What is it, that I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: I think the reason is `column` is local. for each parallel, `column` is initialized to zero, but should not be. Let it out of the `for` loop.

Comment: Floating-point addition is not associative - small rounding errors accumulate in a different way if the order of summing of the elements is changed. Also 64-bit or 80-bit internal precision could be used in the serial case which is lost during the reduction phase as each value is converted to single precision.

Comment: @Hristo Iliev: Thanks, I didn't know floats are not associative. Just for fun I'll try to use doubles instead and observe if the error gets smaller or remains unchanged :)

Comment: A first attempt of using double values just resulted in a larger error. On the other hand, I could not find any race conditions either.  Neither `tan_hd.data` nor `row` are changed/written to during the `omp` section and `omp` should take care of `column`...

Comment: Oh, another thought: in what order of magnitude could the f-p arithmetic errors be? The array consists of 11.5 million columns of audio data ranging from -1.0 to 1.0, so we are dealing with many small values where the f-p error actually might sum up to such a big error... What do you think?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, I don't see any data races too and that's why my next guess was that it is due to rounding errors. Having an array with many positive and negative values could easily result in catastrophic cancellation.

Comment: Switching from floats to doubles would not improve the precision if you subtract similar values. It would only increase the amount of precision being lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Kahan summation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)

- It has the same algorithmic complexity as a naive summation
- It will greatly increase the accuracy of a summation, without requiring you to switch data types to double.

By rewriting your code to implement it:

```
for(int row = 0; row < tan_hd.rows; row++) {
    float sum = 0.0, c = 0.0;
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum, +:c)
    for(int column = 0; column < tan_hd.cols; column++) {
        float y = tan_hd.data[column * tan_hd.rows + row] - c;
        float t = sum + y;
        c = (t - sum) - y;
        sum = t;
    }
    sum = sum - c;
    printf("row %d: %f", row, sum);
}
```

You can additionally switch all `float` to `double` to achieve a higher precision, but since your array is a `float` array, there should only be differences in the number of signficant numbers at the end.

Comment: The problem is not that much in the intermediate summing but rather when the local values of `sum` are combined into the final result and it happens that some of them have opposite signs and close absolute values.

Comment: @HristoIliev: Since OP said: "The array consists of 11.5 million columns of audio data ranging from -1.0 to 1.0", the problem **is** in the intermediate summing.